Information content of a square wave with random cycles
How can I measure the information content of a square wave with random cycles?

This signal has the values of 0 and 1, but the time that it remains in one of the states changes, so the time is important.
If I had two square waves with random cycles, how could I measure the shared information between them?

Attempt to take its Fourier Transform, and count the number of peaks above a certain threshold. For two signals, attempt to cross-correlate the positions of their Fourier Transform peaks...

how is it related to the information? can you explain more?

By "shared information" do you mean the Shannon mutual information? That's impossible to know without knowing the distribution these signals are taken from.

For example, if one signal is just the other one slowed down 5×, do you consider them to have a large amount of shared information, because they have the same number of jumps? Or a small amount, because the time between jumps is very different? Or a small amount, because they are only in the same state about half the time which is no better than chance? Or a large amount, because if you know that one signal is just a slower version of the other then each signal uniquely determines the other?

Why this advice ? In general,"hiding" information into a signal is by means of repetition, i.e., the information is repeated with a variable periodicity, and Fourier transform can be useful for frequencies "dis-entangling". But, as @Toph made the remark, you have to make clear for others and hopefully for you what you mean exactly by "information content"...
